# Constrained Optimization of ANN Inputs

Tags: python, optimization, neural-network, constraints

I'm trying to solve a constrained optimization problem in python using suited algorithms such as simulated annealing.

So basically, I have a set of inputs and outputs that describe a complex chemical process. I built an ANN model with a specific structure to represent this process. My next task is to use this ANN within an optimization framework to maximize the overall economics. This would involve formulating an objective function and a set of equality and inequality constraints which can be mathematically derived from the ANN's inputs and outputs. I would like therefore to know how to describe the optimization part in python. Ultimately, the result would be an optimal set of values for each input variable to improve the process's economics.

Comment: Is there a specific Python programming question? This seems way too broad for SO without edits to make it more specific in scope.

Comment: In addition to not being about Python, I'm not clear on how SA in your first sentence fits with the rest of the question. This is too broad.